# Gummi TEX editor not displaying matrix

Tags: math-mode, packages, gummi

very new to LaTeX, only ever done it on Stackoverflow, never in an editor, so this is a very basic question but my attempt at displaying a matrix is not working, Gummi says that a fatal error occurs but it doesn't go into any more detail. Here is my text. (I have a left a comment indicating where the fatal error is)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%Gummi|065|=)
\title{
  \underline{\LARGE{\textbf{Scheduling Solution}}} \\
  \Large Modelling With Graphs
  }
\author{Retsek}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{ProblemA3}
\end{center}

\underline{\Large{\textbf{A.3.1}}}
\\ \\
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} % Fatal error occurs here

\end{document}
```

Comment: remove the `\\ \\ ` and then use a math display so `\[\begin{pmatrix}..... \end{pmatrix} \]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank-you that worked, can you explain why? I'm not familiar with a 'math display'. On stackoverflow you don't need one, and all of my experience comes from there.

Comment: stackoverflow does not use tex at all but mathjax, a javascript library that _only_ emulates latex math mode, it uses `$$` and `$` to mark math here you use `\[` (which is actually the default display math marker in mathjax as well).